# How to solve the 'package not available in stable-enough version' error of composer?

Tags: json, git, composer-php

Recently, I've been doing a lot of research about Composer minimum-stability. I get into the official documentation and read about the minimum-stability change. But, even so I cant get the composer to install the dependencies.

I have the root package and two others, let's call them packageA and packageB.
When I required the packageB in the root package, the packageB has to bring with him the packageA, but that's when i'm getting the error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for packageB/packageB dev-master -> satisfiable by packageA/packageA[dev-master].
> - packageB/packageB dev-master requires packageA/packageA dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A type in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting.

The root package short version of my composer.json

```
    {
      "require": {      
        "packageB/packageB": "dev-master"
      },
      "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:packageB/packageB.git"
        }
      ],
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
    }
```

The packageA short version of my composer.json

```
    {
      "require": {      

      },
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
    }
```

The packageB short version of my composer.json

```
    {
      "require": {      
        "packageA/packageA": "dev-master"
      },
      "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:packageA/packageA.git"
        }
      ],
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
    }
```

The root required packageB that requires packageA, but the packageB says that can't find packageA in the matching conditions.

### What I'm doing wrong?

### Thanks a lot since now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### I found the proper solution.

Here's what I did.

First:

> I removed the minimum-stability field inside the composer.json of my packages A and B; For the minumum-stability is a root-only field. As, described in this [link] https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability).

But the real solution was, as I was working with my own private package, I was using bitbucket to host the two packages, pointing the repos in the "repositories" field inside my composer.json inside of the root composer and the packageB composer.

### And that is what was wrong.

As described in this [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#package-not-found), the composer's root package has to include the link of all the repos inside the repositories field.

Being just like so:

The root package short version of my composer.json

```
{
  "require": {      
    "packageB/packageB": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:packageB/packageB.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:packageA/packageA.git"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

The packageA short version of my composer.json

```
{
    "require": {      

    }
}
```

The packageB short version of my composer.json

```
{
  "require": {      
    "packageA/packageA": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

### Hope it works, because it worked for me. Peace out!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I was just about to RTFM (Read The Full Manual) in order to figure out how to do this. Now, instead, I created a public gist to try and remember this: https://gist.github.com/ulrikkold/6893632472eb07a8b15b

Comment: Thank you @user3396974 
This worked perfectly for me, but what about if you don't want to have "dev" as minimum-stability?
If I remove that, then it doesn't work anymore.
Have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

change minimum stability to dev from stability like:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```