# php composer package: problem with dev-master version

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I have this problem with composer. I created one package which is connected to github. I would like to set composer to use: **dev-master** version of my github code, not **tag**. But this is what i get during installing package:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a version of package zerig/url-parser matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an e
  xplicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.
```

When i create tag on github. When i update package on composer and when i delete all versions exept one tag version, then it works. But i would like to use **dev-master** version. Because every change force me to do a lot of operations.

This is what i tried and think, that it will help. But Not. **composer.json**:

```
"require": {
    "php" : ">=5.6.0",
    "zerig/url-parser": "dev-master"
},
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: have you tried `@dev` as version ? Using it and it successfully grabs the dev-master on github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the 'package not available in stable-enough version' error of composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536978/how-to-solve-the-package-not-available-in-stable-enough-version-error-of-compo)

Comment: I use this: "zerig/url-parser": "@dev" and it not helped at all. It choose the latest versions of tags, but never dev-master